# JSON io writer delete JSONObject on Android

Tags: java, android, json

I'm currently using the library JSON-io. I created a desktop application which when a person want to log in in the system send an JSONObject with his username and password. Then the server send back the response if the person is allowed or not (also a JSONObject). Until here everything works fine. 
Now i want to make an Android app. I take the same code than before for login but the application crashes.
The code for login is launch from an AsyncTask and i put the permission to access to Internet to the Manifest.

I perform some testing and it occurs that the method write of JSONWriter "delete" my JSON because on the server side he receives this : {}. I tried to hardcode the JSONObject on the server side (the server's code works fine because we can use the desktop app) but this time the readObject on the android App  receives also {}.
We tried to send jsonObject.toString() and this time it worked (except that the server isn't configured to handle a string).

Do anyone knows why on android the two methods write and readObject are deleting the JSON ?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Here the code i wrote:
On the android App

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // 3 : create a JSON object and send it to server for verification
        JSONObject loginJS = new JSONObject();

        try {
            loginJS.put("type", Type.LOGIN);   // Type is an enum 
            loginJS.put("username", userName);
            loginJS.put("hash", mPassword);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        User user = new User();

        System.out
                .println("User created and ready to connect to the spu for login");
        user.connexionToSPU(); // This method works
        System.out.println("LoginJS = "+loginJS.toString()); At this point the print of the JSON is fine we have {"type":"Login", ....}
        user.sendToSPU(loginJS); //This is where there's a problem
        // 4 : wait response
        JSONObject loginResponseJS = user.receiveFromSPU(); // And when i hard code the JSON on the server side receiveFromSPU get a empty JSON
```

---

Method connexionToSPU:

```
public void connexionToSPU() {
    jswSPU = null;
    jsrSPU = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket(prop.readPropertiesXML("IP_adress_server"),
                Integer.parseInt(prop.readPropertiesXML("port_server")));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        jswSPU = new JsonWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        jsrSPU = new JsonReader(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

---

sendToSPU method

```
public void sendToSPU(JSONObject json) {

    try {
        jswSPU.write(json);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

ReceiveFromSPU method

```
public JSONObject receiveFromSPU() {
    JSONObject json = null;
    try {           
        json = (JSONObject) jsrSPU.readObject();
        System.out.println("JSON FROM THE SERVER : "+json.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
```

Hope it will be sufficiently clear.
Thank you

Comment: It's a project and we were a little bit stressed so we decided to change the server and send String and convert the object on the server into an JSONObject and re send it to a string. But if someone knows why it doesn't work i'm still open.